# Using the Ubiquity Container after all files have been deleted

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, icloud, icloud-drive

We are using the iCloud ubiquity container along with a derivative of `UIDocument` to store a users backup files in iCloud. Recently it occurred to us, that if we delete the files we have stored via the iOS devices settings unter *Settings > Apple-ID > iCloud > Manage Storage*, we are not able to use the ubiquity container anymore.

We still get a URL for the container via `NSFileManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null)` (we are using Xamarin, hence C#, FWIF, but I don't think it matters that much), but neither will saving the `UIDocument` save anything to iCloud (at least not as far as I can tell, *Manage storage* won't show our app, let alone any files), nor will getting saved files with a `NSMetadataQuery` with `SearchScopes = new NSObject[] { NSMetadataQuery.UbiquitousDocumentsScope } }` return anything.

I've tried disabling and enabling iCloud for our app, reinstalling (from visual studio and from TestFlight) and explicitly creating the ubiquity container folder from out app, but to no avail.

Is there anything I can to to re-enable the ubiquity container after it's been deleted?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/IntroductionToiCloud/iCloudUIDoc/AppDelegate.cs This demo maybe useful to you

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thank you very much, but the sample did not address my issue :)